# Как встроить html код в кавычки, код Windows Form?

Tags: c#, html

Хочу сделать автоматизацию создания блоков-div с указанными данными - **{Steve}**, то есть чтобы введённые данные заменяли **{Steve}** в html коде, который вставлен в кавычки.

Вставил html код в кавычки, в код Windows Form, но в ответ получил 90 ошибок. Как мне правильно вставить код?

```
    textBox2.Text = ("            <div class="/zitel">  <!----------- + Steve + ----------->
        < div class="block_ava">
            <img src = "https://cravatar.eu/helmavatar/ + Steve +/190.png" class="avatarka" />
        </div>
        <div class="block_status">
            <div class="nickname">
                <h class="h"> + Steve + </h>
            </div>

            <div class="roles"></div>
        </div>
    </div>");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Экранирование кавычки делается обратным слешем перед ней. Попробуйте. у вас получится! Кроме того, многосторчные символьные константы в сишерпе надо начинать со значка @ перед открывающей кавычкой. Должно помочь!

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, выразиться простым язык. Укажите что нужно сделать?

Comment: в двадцать четвертой строке кода "собаку" перед кавчкой напишите. Там где дальше идут кавычки в строке - перед ними напишите обратный слеш. И если бы Вы код вставили кодом, а не каринкой - я бы просто написал это в коде сам :-)

Comment: Я добавил код в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если единственная проблема в Вашем коде - это вставить строку из нескольких строк с кавычками внутри, то делается это примерно так:

```
    textBox2.Text = $@"            <div class=""/zitel"">  <!----------- { Steve } ----------->
            < div class=""block_ava"">
                <img src = ""https://cravatar.eu/helmavatar/ + Steve +/190.png"" class=""avatarka"" />
            </div>
            <div class=""block_status"">
                <div class=""nickname"">
                    <h class=""h""> + Steve + </h>
                </div>

                <div class=""roles""></div>
            </div>
        </div>";
```

Теперь разберемся, что там происходит: чтобы кавычка в строке вставилась "как кавычка" - её в сишерпной строке надо написать два раза. (в комментарии я Вас нечаянно обманул).

Значок @ позволяет работать с многострочными символьными константами. Это так называемые "буквальные строки", в вообще - [вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/).

Значок доллара позволяет вставлять в фигурных скобках переменные, и в строку будет вставлено их значение - такая вот замена конкатенации строк

А если я не заметил какого то скрытого смысла в вопросе - уточните, пожалуйста. А то то, что я Вам советую - это довольно элментарные вещи, вдруг у Вас проблема в чем то другом?